# fetching multiples values in request POST

Tags: python, django

My method POST:

```
QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'9EDhgdla2l92EsLlits1wbsqVtwTsTBv'], u'id_hito': [u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4'], u'boton_modificar': [u'Enviar']}
```

when i try get `'id_hito'`

```
print request.POST['id_hito']
```

this code prints the last value of `'id_hito'`

out:

```
 4
```

how i can get the full values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django HTTP Request get vs getlist behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143872/django-http-request-get-vs-getlist-behavior)

Comment: See the top answer on the linked question (plus a bit of context in the OP itself).